# UITableView doesn't scrolling while scrolling over the cell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitableview

I created a `UITableView` in a `UIViewController` from the `storyboard` and create custom `tableViewCell` class. Now when I run my project,

1. It is not scrolling when I touch any cell and move up/down.
2. BUT, it scrolls if I start scrolling with the either end of `UItableViewCell` (nearly, 15px of left inset).

I tried to create another fresh tableView, still not working.

I tried to create a tableViewController, still not working.

Then I think the code is NOT the cause of the issue.
Using Xcode 8.2.1

**Below is my code work :**

**Class File**

```
struct Quote {
    var text: String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView?

    let cellIdentifier = "cell"

    // Array of strings for the tableView

    var tableData = [Quote(text: "zadz ad azd azds fsd gdsfsd"), Quote(text: "zakd gqsl jdwld bslf bs ldgis uqh dm sd gsql id hsqdl sgqhmd osq bd zao mos qd"), Quote(text: "azdhsqdl sb ljd ghdlsq h ij dgsqlim dhsqihdùa dbz ai ljsm oqjdvl isq dbvksqjld"), Quote(text: "dsqb jhd gs qdgsq dgsq u hdgs qli hd gsql i dgsq li dhs qij dhlqs dqsdsd.")]

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView?.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: self.cellIdentifier)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        // Return number of rows in table

        return tableData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // Create Resusable Cell, get row string from tableData

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: self.cellIdentifier)! as! cellClass

        let row = indexPath.row

        // Set the labels in the custom cell
        cell.mainText.text = tableData[row].text

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        // Do what you want here

        let selectValue = self.tableData[indexPath.row]

        print("You selected row \(indexPath.row) and the string is \(selectValue)")
    }  
}
```

**And this is my cellClass: (Custom cell)**

```
class cellClass: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainText: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

**Storyboard hierarchy of `UITableView`**

[image: main.storyboard]

Comment: What does your `cellClass` look like? - there is possibly something in the cell that is blocking the touch event on the tableview.

Comment: I edited my question with my cellClass code! :)

Comment: Are you using custom tableviewcell xib ?

Comment: no I only have a viewController with a UItableView inside.

Comment: Then why you are registering your  tableViewcell in `ViewDidLoad` ??

Comment: Sorry that was a try.. I removed this line.

Comment: That's so weird... Never had this trouble before.

Comment: Don't worry, hold on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132991/discussion-between-greenpoison-onetv-and-the-dahiya-boy).

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40388589/how-to-detected-nib-file-table-view-cell-to-make-reusablecell/40394129#40394129) may help

Comment: @UmairAfzal he have no `xib` and he have issue with scrolling only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: I had to uninstall and install Xcode again..

Comment: Strange never happened to me

Comment: In fact, I made a fresh install of Xcode but the error still occurs. I need to build and run my projet on a real device.

Answer (score 1):

You might be have some x-code issues because generally it never happens and I run your project it working properly as usually it works.

Below is code work I have done.

I'm not taking sturcture of array like you, I'm just doing with taking simple array.

my array is

```
arrayData = ["One", "Two", "three", "four"]
```

below is `cellForRow`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell : cellClass = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! cellClass
    cell.lblstates.text = arrayData[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

If you facing any issue then let me know.

Comment: I modified your line:
`let cell : cellClass = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! cellClass`
with:
`let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: self.cellIdentifier)! as! cellClass`
and it works but still have the scrolling issue.

Comment: I can't tell you the error description because of reinstalling Xcode... :D

Comment: Good, keep it up  :p

Answer (score 0):

Check if the user interaction Enabled check of your cell is off or not in the storyboard

Comment: I already set user interaction to ON everywhere... still not working! thx