# Storyboard of a mockup

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, mockups

I am working on an e-commerce based app, and the designer has passed on the mockup to me. !

[This is the mockup the designer has passed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uc1iI.png)

I am working on storyboard of this mockup and I have managed to get to this level as of now.

[image: My storyboard as of now]

There are several views and features which cannot be included in this storyboard now because of the limited space. I know the designer has passed on me the rendered view, which can be seen on scrolling the app.

I wonder which could be the best approach to include all these views in a single storyboard or render them in a single view.
I have looked onto using xib files and calling them from my `viewcontroller` class, which could be a possible solution. But, I want to know, what could be the best solution?

Comment: Select your `ViewController` --> `Size Insector` --> `Simulated Size = Freeform` and change `width` and `height` according to your requirement.

Comment: You should be using TableView. create custom cells and everything will be fine. Here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275727/is-it-possible-to-create-one-tableviewcell-that-can-be-used-in-multiple-table-co/40277758#40277758

Comment: Thank you Bhavin Ramani! It could be of help :)

Comment: Can you also add a picture of the mock-up you have been given? It will make it much easier to give specific tips (e.g. table/collection/scrollview etc)

Comment: Looking at your question and the way you formulate it, I think you've bitten off a bit more than you can chew and it would be best to take a step back and figure out some of the basics first.

Comment: The link is already in question, which was edited by some mods, and it's linked as URL https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uc1iI.png! What could be your suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution is use Storyboard so that you have all screens at one place. But keep one thing in mind that start doing the whole project in XCODE 8  storyboard (Because XCODE 7 and 8 storyboards are not fully compatible with each other). So that you get compatibility with previous iOS versions also (< iOS 10)

Now as far as design is concerned, I would like to suggest you use autolayouts and proportional layout.

your View controller will always have self.view. Start on that view. First add navigation controller (with root view controller as your first prefered view controller on app start) or simply add one toolbar. Then add one UIScrollView to whole remaining space. Then start with your design inside UIScrollView. Don't forget to provide contentSize of UIScrollView.

For any help, feel free to ask.

Comment: One more question, now the UIScrollView is not working in this particular view, how do I work on it, so that the scroll view is visible as per the mockup?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be using a `tableView` with multiple prototype cells for this kind of problem. Well, going through the concept as mentioned, I could easily scroll in the `storyboard` and maintain my design as per the mockup.