# Instantiate custom table view cell from xib failed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Here is the inheritance tree of my table view cells.

```
 +----------------+
 | UITableViewCel |
 +-------+--------+
         ^
         |
 +-------+--------+
 |  BaseFormCell  |
 +-------+--------+
         ^
         |
+--------+---------+
| TypedFormCell<T> |
+--------+---------+
         ^
         |
+--------+----------+
| TextFieldFormCell |  : TypedFormCell<String>
+-------------------+
```

where `TextFieldFormCell` has an associated xib file which is used to instantiate itself.

When I call `Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TextFieldFormCell", owner: nil, options: nil)`, an exception is thrown and says

> [< UITableViewCell 0x7fe89584fa00 > setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this
>   class is not key value coding-compliant for the key nameLabel.

I noticed that the xib didn't instantiate a TextFieldFormCell for me. Instead, it created a `UITableViewCell` and tried to inject the `nameLabel` to `UITableViewCell`, which caused the exception.

Does this mean that IB doesn't support generic classes or classes inherit from generic classes?

Here is the GitHub repo of this demo. https://github.com/hikui/TypedCellDemo

Comment: this means your xib name is not correct. Can you check "TextFieldFormCell" is really the correct name you passed in Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TextFieldFormCell", owner: nil, options: nil)

Comment: chcek this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275727/is-it-possible-to-create-one-tableviewcell-that-can-be-used-in-multiple-table-co/40277758#40277758

Comment: @aman.sood I've checked it multiple times.

Comment: IB  works with Obj-C runtime. So using a generic table view cell in storyboard won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative way:

Register the nib file in your class `viewDidLoad`

```
    let nibName = UINib(nibName: "<nibName>", bundle:nil)
    self.tableView.registerNib(nibName, forCellReuseIdentifier: "<CellIdentifier>")
```

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
    let cell : TextFieldFormCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "<CellIdentifier>") as! TextFieldFormCell?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom tableview cell by using this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellIdentifier = "textFieldFormCell"
        var cell : TextFieldFormCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as! TextFieldFormCell?
        if (cell == nil) {

            cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TextFieldFormCell", owner: nil, options: nil)?[0] as? TextFieldFormCell
        }

        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        return cell!
    }
```