# UITableView and custom UITableViewCell using .xib

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

In my app I am using a custom tableViewCell using a xib file. I create the .xib file outlet the labels etc to my TableViewCell class

In my ViewController the code I used to populate and show the cell on the table view is as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let transaction = statementArray[indexPath.row]
    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("StatementCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! StatementCell
    
    
    
    cell.transAmount.text = String(transaction.transAmount)
    cell.transDesc.text = transaction.transDesc
    cell.transFees.text = String(transaction.transFees)
    
    return cell
}
```

I am aware that the way tableViews work is that they reuse the cell that goes off the screen. Is the way i am loading the .xib and populating the cell correct? Or do I have to add something to my code?

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use a .xib? You can create multiple cells in the same table view in Interface Builder.

Comment: I am using a .xib because i will be using different cells depending on the data i have

Comment: Where is the problem? You can create as many cells as you like in the same table view with different UI elements, sizes etc. Just drag cells into the table view and assign an identifier and (optional) a class. It's much more convenient than using extra .xibs.

Comment: @vadian may be Xib is more handy for reusing the cell in multiple tableViews ?

Comment: @pavlos please have a loot at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275727/is-it-possible-to-create-one-tableviewcell-that-can-be-used-in-multiple-table-co/40277758#40277758

Comment: @UmairAfzal Yes in this case a XIB is more handy but the question doesn't seem to be about multiple table views.

Answer (score 4):

First you need to register your custom cell with UITableView

```
yourTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "StatementCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")
```

then in UITableView Delegate method cellForRowAt you need to write

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! StatementCell
cell.textLabel?.text = "Sample Project"
return cell
```

now you can access your UITableViewCell properties with cell.propertyName

and you must take care that  "cellIdentifier" and "forCellReuseIdentifier" both value must be same.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing is you need to register your class for reuse identifier in `viewDidLoad` method.

```
YourTable.registerclass(tablecell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "identifier"
```

And make sure you have connect all the required outlets.

Comment: So this line of code is basicaly to register the custom cell class in order to reuse the cell?

Comment: yes, In my code I also used....Before applying this I got few crashes and after using it works fine....

Answer (score 0):

FIrst Register Custom cell nibCalss in tableview

```
let str1 : NSString = "StatementCell"

tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "StatementCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: str1 as String)
```

Now initialise tableviewcell

```
let cell1:StatementCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: str1 as String) as! StatementCell!
```

Now access tableviewcell outlet collection.