# error message "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" even its cell is not nil

Tags: swift, xcode

xcode: 9.4.1

I'm creating a simple table view but I keep getting the same
"Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
error when it comes to set a value to a component in each cell.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var conditionTable: UITableView!

    var conditions = [Condition]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        conditionTable.register(ConditionCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "conditionCell")
        conditionTable.delegate = self
        conditionTable.dataSource = self
        setInitData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func setInitData() {
        conditions.append(Condition(name: "a"))
        conditions.append(Condition(name: "b"))
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return conditions.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell: ConditionCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "conditionCell") as? ConditionCell
            else {
                fatalError()
        }
        print(cell.conditionLabel.text)
//        cell.setCell(condition: conditions[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

}
```

I did name my custom cell "ConditionCell" and I did name the identified "conditionCell".

Here is my custom cell class.
I did add the component(label) reference to the class.
It looks like the custom view class is successfully loaded (not nil)
however its component (label) is not.

```
import UIKit

class ConditionCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var conditionLabel: UILabel!

    func setCell(condition: Condition) {
        print(conditionLabel)
        conditionLabel.text = condition.name
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the outlet connected to a label in the storyboard?

Comment: refer to this for creating custom cells: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275727/is-it-possible-to-create-one-tableviewcell-that-can-be-used-in-multiple-table-co/40277758#40277758

Comment: If the cell is designed in Interface Builder you **must not** register the cell. And remove the `guard ... fatalError()`. Force unwrap the cell type. If it works once it works forever. And don't name methods with leading `set...`.

Comment: Removing the registering part did solve the problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line :

```
conditionTable.register(ConditionCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "conditionCell")
```

It requires `UINib`. Change it to:

```
conditionTable.register(UINib(nibName: "ConditionCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "conditionCell")
```

For more details check this :

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614937-register